# Is it possible to get PhD in Statistics for an actuary?

Tags: career-path, early-career

The question is pretty straightforward.

I'm an actuary with a bachelor and a master degree in actuarial science. I have already worked in the insurance industry, I have programming experience and some data science/machine learning background thanks to Kaggle, MOOCs and similar stuff.

As an actuary, I have had a lot of stats classes but I'm not sure if what I have studied is enough for a PhD in Statistics or if I lack a lot of things (i.e. I have never studied measure theory). What do you think about it? Is it possible to enter in a good statistics program in Europe?

My research would be in ML and similar things applied to actuarial. I also want to enter in a good university because I want to become a professor.

Comment: Have you considered doing a PhD in data science rather than a traditional PhD in mathematical statistics?  You might find this to be a better choice for your interests.

Comment: Actually I had but the problem is that a lot of Ms/PhDs in data science seems to be just programs to attract people. They doesn't seem to be rigorous and serious. So I was considering a PhD in Statistics (maybe at an university where they have a data science concentration) where I can apply data science methods in my research. What do you think about this option? I'm much more interested in practical applications, rather then theory and demonstrations. Maybe a PhD in Applied Statistics could an option? Do you know any good applied programs?